# Further Diagnosis of BSOD 124

Tags: bsod

We are experiencing spurious BSOD's (about once in 1..2 days, time varies) on a Hyper-V Server. I've come as far as this:

[Bug Check code 124](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb725851.aspx)

e.g.
0x00000124 (0x0000000000000000, 0xfffffa800a3bf558, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000).

Parameter 1, 3 and 4 are all zero. Parameter 2 (some struct's address) varies.

**(a) Memory Check Tool**
[Windows Memory Diagnostic](http://oca.microsoft.com/de/windiag.asp) only checks the first 4GB (the machine has 12GB) - can anyone recommend a memory check tool?

**(b) Further Diagnosis**
I don't understand how to go on with the error information. I've read a handful of articles & PDF's, but still don't know how to go on. Bug Check

System: Intel i7-920, SuperMicro X8SAX, 12GB RAM, 5 SATA drives, running Hyper-V Server.

The system was running fine for over a month with just one virtual machine on it, crashes started after migrating another physical machine (W2K3 Server) to it. Windows Updates are applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More often than not BSOD are caused by driver issues, I would probably make sure that all the drivers on your server are signed and WHQL approved.

To track down the root cause of your problem would be to open the crash dump in WinDBG and find the exact process/command that caused the fault, even then this isnt always as clear cut as you would think.

Comment: sorry just reread your question and the only way to find the root cause would be by analysing the dump file with a tool like WinDBG. KB http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315263 walks you through the process of analysing a small dump file and is probably a good starting point